# root route problem in laravel 6.2 RouteServiceProvider

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing, laravel-6.2

i have defined these two different routes in laravel RouteServiceProvider like this:

```
protected function mapABCRoutes()
    {
        Route::prefix('abc')
            ->middleware('web')
            ->namespace($this->namespace)
            ->group(base_path('routes/abc.php'));
    }

protected function mapXYZRoutes()
    {
        Route::prefix('xyz')
            ->middleware('web')
            ->namespace($this->namespace)
            ->group(base_path('routes/xyz.php'));
    }
```

and i defined a route in **abc.php**

```
Route::get('/', function(){ return '<h1>ABC Admin</h1>'; })->name('abc.dashboard');
```

all defined routes in **abc.php** are working as well except **route('abc.dashboard')**. it throws a 404 with message *"The requested resource /abc was not found on this server."*
same thing resulting for **xyz.php** im working with all of this things in an ubuntu using laravel 6.2 in apache with mod rewrite enabled. i cant understand why these routes are not working? but the same type route works as well on laravels default route in **web.php**

```
Route::get('/', function () { return view('auth.login'); });
```

Answer (score 0):

Route groups doesn't mean you can override the similar routes multiple time, it usually helps to clean the routes files. For instance, I've created separate route files for some of my main modules and put into their respective route files and map in `RouteServiceProvider`.

As you're using web routes here, What you can do here to prefix routes likeso,
for `xyz.php`

```
Route::group( [
'prefix' => 'xyz'],
function ( Router $api ) {
//your routes
});
```

and similar could be done for `abc.php` and so on.

Comment: similar routes?

Comment: not similar route url and route name are different one will result www.hostname.com/abc route name (->name('abc.dashboard')) another will be www.hostname.com/xyz route name : (->name('xyz.dashboard'))

Comment: @MuhammadHabib means if you're trying to access same route twice from separate files. It's not practically possible. The above solutions would work in your case. Give it a try

Answer (score 0):

Not Sure... it's may help you...

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'abc'], function(){
    Route::get('/', function(){ return '<h1>ABC Admin</h1>'; })->name('abc.dashboard');
});
```